# Patching docroot htaccess: file not found

Tags: 8, composer, .htaccess

I tried to create my first patch file in order to reverse the overwriting of the scaffold file .htaccess after executing composer install. I get the following errors:

```
can't find file to patch at input line 5
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/web/.htaccess b/web/.htaccess
|index 6f9123d..4ae5471 100644
|--- a/web/.htaccess
|+++ b/web/.htaccess
--------------------------

Script cd web && patch -p1 < ../patches/htaccess.patch handling the post-drupal-scaffold-cmd event returned with error code 1
```

This is how the patch file looks like:

```
diff --git a/web/.htaccess b/web/.htaccess
index 6f9123d..4ae5471 100644
--- a/web/.htaccess
+++ b/web/.htaccess
@@ -113,7 +113,7 @@ AddEncoding gzip svgz
   #
   # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
   # uncomment the following line:
-  # RewriteBase /
+  RewriteBase /
 
   # Redirect common PHP files to their new locations.
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?/(install.php) [OR]
```

And this is how it is loaded in composer.json:

```
"post-drupal-scaffold-cmd": [
     "cd web && patch -p1 < ../patches/htaccess.patch"
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look your patch already has the path to `web/` in it:

```
--- a/web/.htaccess
+++ b/web/.htaccess
```

Just remove the `cd web &&`  and adjust the path to the patch accordingly.

```
"post-drupal-scaffold-cmd": [
     "patch -p1 < patches/htaccess.patch"
]
```